# Why is my text floating to the left side?

Tags: html, css

day learning CSS and HTML and I recreated a site from some youtube video and I wanted to customize it a bit. So I managed to get the text centered (not only the text, the whole introduction that I have made)
[here is a screen shot of my "progress?"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQrfF.png)

As you can see the text doesn't look good and I don't know how to fix it, here is my code

```css
.presentation {
    display: flex;
    width: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 80vh;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="introduction">
<div class="intro-text">
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. What do you mean by the text doesn't look good? What's the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
text-align: center;
```

In your css of the class intro-text

Answer (score 0):

> Just paste this in your css file.

```
 .presentation {
display: flex;
width: 20%;
margin: auto;
min-height: 80vh;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;}
```

Comment: If this doesn't work add   text-align: center;   to content what you want in centre of your page. Please Upvote if found useful.